# Google map alignment problem in IE7 only

Tags: html, css, google-maps, internet-explorer-7

I'm a beginner and have just about managed to put together this website with one problem remaining. I had other problems aligning the CSS in Internet Explorer 7, so I put an IE7 specific style sheet in. Now one problem remains and I have tried everything to fix it but just can't get it to work. It is on this page http://bit.ly/fxggEu (in IE7 only.)

The 'Paleohori village' text and the Google Map are positioned way too low down and the bottom part of the Google map cannot be seen as it's been cut and is'hiding' behind the footer. It is aligning exactly how I want in other browsers with the caption in the right place, a gap between the image and the google map, and the google map positioned over the top part of the footer.

I have tried playing with the margins, padding, google map size, z-index etc... But without any success. If anyone can help I'd be most grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix is to add `position: relative` to `#container`.

On an unrelated note, you have on `#footer` this rule: `top-margin: -130px;`. It should be `margin-top`, but you don't want that style anyway, so get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks very much @thirtydot, that has almost sorted my problem... So I added the position: relative and now the Google map is fully seen and positioned correctly in relation to the footer. However, there is still the large gap between the content above it (caption and image), and in other browsers the gap has been altogether removed. Do you have any idea how I can change this so that there is just a small gap between the google map and the content above it in all the browsers? Many thanks.

Comment: The reason for the massive gap in IE7 is `margin-top: 155px` on `#main #paleohori`. This sucks, but you can remove the margin just for IE7 if you like by adding a rule *under* the first margin rule: `*margin-top: 0`. That way, all browsers will read `margin-top: 155px`, and then only IE7 and lower will read `*margin-top: 0`. Ugly, but should work.

Comment: Thanks very much @thirtydot - I am trying to figure out exactly how to implement your solution, so do I add the *margin-top: 0 into the same Div (#main #paleohori) CSS rule just as a new line like I would add any other rule? Do I just need to do this for the IE7 specific style sheet? I tried adding it into that Div (like this:  margin-top: 155px; *margin-top: 0;) but nothing seemed to change. As you can see I'm a real beginner so if you can give me more specific advice on how I need to include it in the code I'd really appreciate that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You *could* have added `margin-top: 0` to your IE7 stylesheet, but your IE7 stylesheet is above your normal stylesheet. It should instead be below it. But, *you can't change that now*, because I don't know what will screw up (there's a lot of stuff in your IE7 stylesheet). The easiest way to apply my fix is to do this: under this line: `<link href="lenistyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` add this: `<!--[if IE 7]><style type="text/css">#main #paleohori { margin-top: 0 }</style><![endif]-->`.